# How to remove placeholder on focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus, placeholder

I made this simple function to add placeholder in browsers that do not support it:

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/UCoHANA/1)

The question is: How can I add to that function the possibility to remove the placeholder when the user click inside it?

Comment: Why you are using place holder for this one you can use blur also placeholder is the inbuilt attributes of browser ie does not support this remeber!

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Try to use [removeAttr()](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr) like,

```
$('input,textarea').focus(function(){
   $(this).removeAttr('placeholder');
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/swX6V/)

To get the `placeholder value` again on `blur()` try this,

```
$('input,textarea').focus(function(){
   $(this).data('placeholder',$(this).attr('placeholder'))
          .attr('placeholder','');
}).blur(function(){
   $(this).attr('placeholder',$(this).data('placeholder'));
});
```

[Demo 1](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/swX6V/151/)

Comment: Thank you Rohan. It is working properly in Chrome.
Altough is not working in Explorer (v. 8), that is where mostly i need this function. Do you know how can i do to make this code working also on Explorer 8? Thank you!

Comment: If you need i have create a new JSBin:  http://jsbin.com/avIfuDAf/1

Comment: @johnnyfittizio this is because `placeholder` not works in `IE 8`, for this you have to set `value` of your `elements` on `focus and blur` See demo http://jsbin.com/avIfuDAf/3

Comment: How can exactly do that in the code you post? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you Rohan! Somehow i have missed tour last jsbin..
It works perfectly!

Answer (score 36):

There is no need to use javascript function to accomplish this, a simpler solution is:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="enter your text" onfocus="this.placeholder=''" onblur="this.placeholder='enter your text'" />
```

Comment: Nice one! it is working perfectly

Comment: @C_J this is brilliant..

Answer (score 20):

CSS worked for me:

```
input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: Best solution for modern browsers.

Comment: Any Solution for FireFox

Comment: Nilesh: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/p/placeholder/

Answer (score 1):

```
$("input[placeholder]").each(function () {
    $(this).attr("data-placeholder", this.placeholder);

    $(this).bind("focus", function () {
        this.placeholder = '';
    });
    $(this).bind("blur", function () {
        this.placeholder = $(this).attr("data-placeholder");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A very simple and comprehensive solution for this is which works in Mozila, IE, Chrome, Opera and Safari:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="your placeholder" onfocus="this.placeholder=''" onblur="this.placeholder='your placeholder'" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('*').focus(function(){
  $(this).attr("placeholder",'');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This hope it helps

```
$('input,textarea').focus(function()
{
$(this).attr('placeholder','');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input').focus(function()
{
  $(this).attr('placeholder','');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

For browsers that don't support placeholder you can use this: 
https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder. 
Add the placeholder attribute normally as for HTML5, then call this plugin: `$('[placeholder]').placeholder();`. Then use Rohan Kumar's code and will be cross-browser.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution on click not on focus:

```
$(document).on('click','input',function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var place_val = $this.attr('placeholder');
    if(place_val != ''){
        $this.data('placeholder',place_val).removeAttr('placeholder');
    }
}).on('blur','input',function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var place_val = $this.data('placeholder');
    if(place_val != ''){
        $this.attr('placeholder',place_val);
    }
});
```